# Listing folders with absolute paths

Tags: cmd

I have some subfolders inside a given folder that I would like to list their absolute paths in cmd. Is there a way to go about it?

```
cd D:\

mkdir Testdir
mkdir TestdirA
mkdir TestdirB

dir Testdir > Testdir\TestdirA\files.txt

dir /B /D

dir /B /S /D Rem This is list the files too.
```

When I run the code above I do not get the paths but instead the names of the subfolders.

Comment: `@for /d %i in (testdir) do @echo %~fi`

Comment: This seems not to be working as expected

Comment: Do you want to list just the directory `Testdir` or recursively list all the directories inside of it as well?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the `/D` option of the `dir` command, so let me recommend to type `dir /?` into a Command Prompt window and read the output text. You may have meant `/A:D` (or `/A:D-H-S`), right?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand the question, I think the following will produce what you want. The `/A:D` switch specifies to list directories only.

```
DIR /S /B /A:D "C:\Testdir"
```

Comment: Thank you for this I would not want the directories to be listed recursively. Just list the directories in Testdir-not recursively